# Ways to store access token that expires every 10 minutes in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am looking to evaluate ways to store access token that I obtain after I login to my react native app. Currently I am able to store the username and password in the keychain using react native so that I can call the login api again to get the new access token. Couple of options that I have already found out are as below.

1) Using AyncStorage to store the access token.
2) Create a db table to store the value.
3) Redux persistent store to

But the complication that I am facing is the access token expires after 10 minutes. I am looking to see if somebody can propose a seamless option to check if the access token is valid and if its not then call the login api with the credentials and store the new access token. This has to be in the background and should not have any effect on the user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Redux you can store the expire time in your reducer and check it everytime the user takes an action which relies on token, as well as in your componentWillMount.

The same logic can be applied if you have a database, but in this case you will make a request to the server to check it. You can also use the server timezone to avoid relying on client clock.

You can also store it locally and retrieve this data when needed.

If it's a single screen, then you can call a function to check it using a setTimeout of 600000 mile seconds (it's equal to 10 minutes).

Hope it helps.